# How to set current directory for ES6 dynamic import function

Tags: javascript, node.js, dynamic, ecmascript-6, import

I have this directory tree:

```
project
  |
  -> dir1
      |
      -> dir2
          |
          -> module.mjs

     server.mjs
     utils.mjs
```

My current working directory is:

```
 project/
```

Source code of server.mjs

```
async function main(){
    var module = await import("./dir1/dir2/module.mjs");
}

main();
```

Source code of module.mjs

```
//this works!
import utils from "../../utils.mjs";

//this fails!
import utils from "./utils.mjs";
```

It seems that the static import in the module.mjs consider the dot '.' as the directory of itself, not the current working directory.

How to set a current directory for dynamic import?
And the actual base question is: **How to avoid the long '../../.......'** of static imports in a dynamic module.

For example, I wish to have something like this in server.mjs:

```
var module = await import("./dir1/dir2/module.mjs",{cwd:"project/"});
```

Or, in dynamic module, able to use:

```
import utils from './utils.mjs'
```

instead of:

```
import utils from '../../long dot dot/utils.mjs'
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `process.cwd()`, it returns the directory from which you run nodejs.

Comment: I know that's how to get cwd, but how to avoid the long ../../....... of static imports in dynamic module

Comment: Using `process.cwd()` you should be able to get the path to your file : `import utils from (process.cwd() + '/utils.mjs')`.

Comment: @Abrikot it doesn't work, the right side of "from" must be string constant

Comment: @Abrikot adding the parentheses still leads to SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Comment: Oh, right, I didn't know. My solution won't work, then. You should then try with the function-like ` import`  keyword: `await import(process.cwd() + '/utils.mjs')`.

Comment: i thought of using `await` keyword too, but that means i have to wrap the whole `module.mjs` file in a `async` function, hm, this is sad :(

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there's no way to do **static import** in a dynamic imported module with the dot `.` refer to current working directory yet.

So, the work-around is still using the dotdot-slashslash...

I've submitted a new feature request to Node.js team here: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/31822